# Change comma to dot for every cell in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I have column with numbers. These numbers uses a comma as the decimal separator. I would like a dot instead for the comma for every cell in this column.
This is what I have:

```
Col1    Col2    NumCol
Value 1 Value 2 12,3
Value 3 Value 4 1,23
Value 5 Value 6 99,8
```

This is what I want:

```
Col1    Col2    NumCol
Value 1 Value 2 12.3
Value 3 Value 4 1.23
Value 5 Value 6 99.8
```

I am familiar with the REPLACE-function. However I don't know how to use it when it involves a whole column. How would a function like that look like?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()`

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.NumCol, replace(numcol, ',', '.') as NewNumCol
from table t;
```

EDIT : As side noted by @barthofland if you have large value then only one `replace()` might fail. So, you need instead :

```
replace(replace(numcol, '.', ''), ',', '.')
```

Comment: As a side note, I would like to remark that you might want to mind larger values, where a dot might be used as a thousand separator: "1.234.567,89". If you replace the dots with commas, those values will become invalid. So before replacing commas with dots, you might first want to remove existing dots: `REPLACE(REPLACE(numcol, '.', ''), ',', '.')`.